# How can I split a string into an array from the columns list specified as array values in another column?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following dataframe. I need help in coding in Spark Scala to split the column list specified as an array in column `d`. For e.g. for row 2, since the values in column `d` are "b" and "c", the code should split columns `b` and `c`.

```
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+
|         a|       b|                  c|     d|
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+
| India, US|   4,5,6|apple, banana, pear|[a, b]|
|Canada, LA|13,14,15|  berry, strawberry|[b, c]|
|    UK, US|22,23,24|       carrot, plum|[a, c]|
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+
```

Here is the code to create the dataframe:

```
import spark.implicits._
    val data = Seq(
      ("India, US", "4,5,6", "apple, banana, pear", Array("a", "b")),
      ("Canada, LA", "13,14,15", "berry, strawberry", Array("b", "c")),
      ("UK, US", "22,23,24", "carrot, plum", Array("a", "c"))
    )


    val df = data.toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each column have to be split into new column, columns to split can be taken, and new columns created with `array_contains` function:

```
val arrayColumn = "d"
val splittableColumns = df.columns.filterNot(_.equals(arrayColumn))
val result = splittableColumns.foldLeft(df)((acc,columnName)=>
  acc.withColumn(s"${columnName}_split",
    when(array_contains(col(arrayColumn), columnName), split(col(columnName), ",")))
)
```

Result is:

```
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|a         |b       |c                  |d     |a_split     |b_split     |c_split             |
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|India, US |4,5,6   |apple, banana, pear|[a, b]|[India,  US]|[4, 5, 6]   |null                |
|Canada, LA|13,14,15|berry, strawberry  |[b, c]|null        |[13, 14, 15]|[berry,  strawberry]|
|UK, US    |22,23,24|carrot, plum       |[a, c]|[UK,  US]   |null        |[carrot,  plum]     |
+----------+--------+-------------------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to split them with the same name instead of "_split" suffix? I don't want to duplicate columns that were split.

Comment: sure, just use `acc.withColumn(columnName,` in snippet.